# Compare months in excel

Tags: excel, compare

how to compare months in excel, for example I have `Nov` in `cell A1` and `Nov` as well in `cell B1`, so if those are equal will display `1` else diplay `0`.

Answer (score 3):

If those are just text values try

`=IF(A1=B1,1,0)`

or are they actual dates formatted to show the month? In which case try

`=IF(MONTH(A1)=MONTH(B1),1,0)`

Comment: how about comparing just the month to this -> DATE(YEAR(I3),MONTH(I3)+3,DAY(I3))